# Merge accounts after activating enterprise SSO

Tags: auth0

I am trying to understand how to ensure frictionless account access for users that registered their a personal account with their corporate or university address once  adding their corporate or university Identity Provider to Auth0.

I understand that by default [users can link accounts manually](https://auth0.com/docs/manage-users/user-accounts/user-account-linking). But for the described scenario that sounds cumbersome and might turn users away.

Is there an alternative workflow for this?

Comment: Use Auth0 rules for that. You can find it under Auth Pipeline. Then create a custom rule to merge accounts. If you want to add it as a feature use Auth0 Management APIs to do that.